# cannot load tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My code is, simply, executing in pycharm:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get the following messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/Kaggle/Salt_pretrain/pretrain_model.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/anaconda3/envs/May2018_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/anaconda3/envs/May2018_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/anaconda3/envs/May2018_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/anaconda3/envs/May2018_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/activations/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.activations import elu
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/anaconda3/envs/May2018_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import activations
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/anaconda3/envs/May2018_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/activations.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import backend as K
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/anaconda3/envs/May2018_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/backend.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.layers import base as tf_base_layers
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/anaconda3/envs/May2018_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/anaconda3/envs/May2018_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import InputSpec
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/anaconda3/envs/May2018_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
  File "/Users/peterwills/PyCharmProjects/anaconda3/envs/May2018_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.backend import abs
ImportError: cannot import name 'abs'
```

My tensor flow version is 1.9.0.
My Keras version is: 2.2.2
...cboth in anaconda

I have tried uninstalling tensor flow and protobuf, as suggested elsewhere, to no avail.

Can anyone advise on this?

Comment: maybe `import tensorflow as tf`

Comment: That's how I had it in the code but it got messed up putting in stack overflow. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making a new virtual environment in anaconda and re-installing tensor flow (and a bunch of other unrelated stuff). A bit much, I agree but "only way to be sure".